# Android Studio Profiler Network Overview - отображение кириллицы

Tags: json, android-studio, кодировка

Смотрю через **Profiler** ответы сервера и там кириллица отображается в виде кракозябр. Как сделать, чтобы в **Profiler** кириллица нормально отображалась? А если никак, то можно ли вообще как-нибудь восстановить кодировку, например при помощи стороннего приложения?

Сейчас выглядит примерно так:

```
"name":"РџР»РѕРјР±РёСЂРѕРІРєР° РіСЂСѓР·Р°","key":"packingSealing","params":[{"name":"РљРѕР»РёС‡РµСЃС‚РІРѕ РїР»РѕРјР±","key":"sealCount","type":"INT","possibleValues"
```

Comment: Проблему решили в итоге? Тоже столкнулся

Comment: @Taxi, конкретно через профайлер нет, там все так же. Сейчас смотрю такие вещи через дебагер. Еще можно поставить плагин Okhttp